# Do create extension work in single-user mode in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I can't create postgis extension in single-user mode in postgres. But I can do that from pgadmin.

Is creating extension in single-user mode even possible? Can find any docs on that.

Full info on my question can be seen [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146361/how-extensions-work-in-postgres).

Comment: Do you mean from a psql prompt. Have you checked that you have correct permissions, see the [extension docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createextension.html), which state you typically need superuser or db owner permissions. It is possible you are using psql and pgAdmin with different users?

Comment: Read about single user mode

Comment: I know what single user mode is, but who said you can't use psql to connect to a db in single-user mode.

Comment: You don't need single-user mode. It is only needed for creating the catalogs during bootstrapping. The postgis-extension can be added using normal operations.

Comment: Oh really? Enlighten me how to do that with docker when building the image, so that right after the build users would have completely working geospatial database please =) AFAIK there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, right now I have a [comment on the PostgreSQL mailing list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20150126124133.19763.60605@wrigleys.postgresql.org).

> Why in the world would you think that's a good thing to do?
>
> Single-user mode is a barely-documented disaster recovery aid. It's
>   not meant for routine activity. There are a *whole lot* of behaviors
>   you want that are turned off in single-user mode.
>
> The specific reason why this doesn't work is this bit in
>   heap_create_with_catalog:

```
/*
 * Decide whether to create an array type over the relation's rowtype. We
 * do not create any array types for system catalogs (ie, those made
 * during initdb). We do not create them where the use of a relation as
 * such is an implementation detail: toast tables, sequences and indexes.
 */
if (IsUnderPostmaster && (relkind == RELKIND_RELATION ||
                          relkind == RELKIND_VIEW ||
                          relkind == RELKIND_MATVIEW ||
                          relkind == RELKIND_FOREIGN_TABLE ||
                          relkind == RELKIND_COMPOSITE_TYPE))
    new_array_oid = AssignTypeArrayOid();
```

> We could possibly develop some other mechanism for detecting whether
>   we're within the initdb sequence, but I can't get very excited about
>   treating this as a bug. Single-user mode hasn't been considered a
>   standard user environment since maybe the early 90s.

Comment: It's interesting to note that single user mode is 'highly recommended' for initialisation tasks in the [official Docker Postgres image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/postgres/).